# javascript regex .match stop at a certain string

Tags: javascript, regex

What should I add to this regular expression to stop the search at "/stopHere" and only return what it found up until that string?

```
var string = "http://website.com/#!/goodText=hello/hello//stopHere=badtext";

var reg = string.match(/goodText=.*\/stopHere/);
```

this captures `["goodText=hello/hello/hello/stopHere"]`, so how would i make it exclude "/stopHere" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a capturing group around the part you want to grab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't know if this is the best way, but found something called a [Positive Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
var string = "http://website.com/#!/goodText=hello/hello//stopHere=badtext";    
var reg = string.match(/goodText=.*(?=\/stopHere)/);
// returns: goodText=hello/hello/
```

basically if I put `(?=regex)` at the end, it stops when it finds that!

Comment: thanks @CasimiretHippolyte and thanks for the correction before